# Find Columns and Format as dates

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code from a different posting and I was wondering how I could apply this only to the Sheet3. This code works through all of the sheets and I don't need that. Could anyone possibly help me with this? Thank you so much. Always.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        ExitLoop = False

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            ws.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

            lastRow = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
            ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 2 To lastRow
                With ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i)
                    .FormulaR1C1 = .Value
                End With
            Next i

            ws.Columns(aCell.Column).AutoFit

            Do While ExitLoop = False
                Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    ws.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

                    lastRow = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
                    ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    For i = 2 To lastRow
                        ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value
                    Next i
                Else
                    ExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
```

with:

```
Set ws = worksheets("Sheet3")
```

and remove the last `Next`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by replacing all references of `ws`, which is the variable holding the sheets when looping through all worksheets, with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")`. Please test the following code though note it is untested:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

    Set aCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(1).Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ExitLoop = False

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

        lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").RoThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i)
                .FormulaR1C1 = .Value
            End With
        Next i

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(aCell.Column).AutoFit

        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(1).FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

                lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").RoThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Count).End(xlUp).Row

                For i = 2 To lastRow
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value
                Next i
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If

End Sub
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
```

with

```
set ws = worksheets("sheet3")
```

and remove the

```
Next
```

at the end.